# Thunderbird: Override colors in received HTML emails

Tags: email, html, thunderbird

I need to override default colors in received HTML emails. I have followed this [Howto](http://kb.mozillazine.org/White_on_black_-_Thunderbird), and modified my `userContent.css` accordingly. Basically, I need white text on dark background:

```
$ cat userContent.css
body {
  color: white !important; 
  background-color: #303030 !important;
}

td {
  color: white !important;
  background-color: black !important;
}
```

This works OK for the background color, but the my desired font color (white) is being ignored, even when I use `!important`.

How can I make sure, that all received HTML emails have white font on dark bacckground?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have changed the colors only on two HTML elements (`body` and `td`). You may need to do that for other elements, or `*` for all elements.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. It works but I would prefer if I could specifically make the text in the html white on black. Is there another element apart from body and td that can be configured?

Comment: @Filbuntu I think that almost any element could be set to a different color. So either you use `*` as I've said (in case this works here, but no guarantee), or you need to find each element by testing (or using development tools).

Comment: Thanks for the comment! I am eager test elements but I could not find a helpful list of elements. Could you share a link with suitable elements I could test?

Comment: @Filbuntu You need to look at a list of HTML elements (for various HTML versions) such as [this one on W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/default.asp). Each element that can contain text as a possible descendent should be considered.

Comment: Thank you for the hint and link! I will do some trial & error when I find time.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use `text-color` instead of `color`.

Comment: Consider adding some sources to backup your suggested solution.

Comment: Why `text-color`? It doesn't appear to exist! See for instance: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS/#properties